# How to read probability Vector in Spark Dataframe LogisticRegression output

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read the first probability on the logistic regression output so that I may perform decile binning on it.

Below is some test code that just emulates the outputs with a vector.

```
    val r = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(("jane", Vectors.dense(.98)),
        ("tom", Vectors.dense(.34)),
        ("nancy", Vectors.dense(.93)),
        ("tim", Vectors.dense(.02)),
        ("larry", Vectors.dense(.033)),
        ("lana", Vectors.dense(.85)),
        ("jack", Vectors.dense(.84)),
        ("john", Vectors.dense(.09)),
        ("jill", Vectors.dense(.12)),
        ("mike", Vectors.dense(.21)),
        ("jason", Vectors.dense(.31)),
        ("roger", Vectors.dense(.76)),
        ("ed", Vectors.dense(.77)),
        ("alan", Vectors.dense(.64)),
        ("ryan", Vectors.dense(.52)),
        ("ted", Vectors.dense(.66)),
        ("paul", Vectors.dense(.67)),
        ("brian", Vectors.dense(.68)),
        ("jeff", Vectors.dense(.05)))).toDF(CSMasterCustomerID, MLProbability)
    var result = r.select(CSMasterCustomerID, MLProbability)
    val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField(CSMasterCustomerID, StringType, false), StructField(MLProbability, DoubleType, true)))
    result = sqlContext.createDataFrame(result.map((r: Row) => {
        r match {
            case Row(mcid: String, probability: Vector) =>
                RowFactory.create(mcid, probability(0))
        }
    }), schema)
```

This fails to compile saying:

```
<console>:56: error: type mismatch;
found   : Double
required: Object
Note: an implicit exists from scala.Double => java.lang.Double, but
methods inherited from Object are rendered ambiguous.  This is to avoid
a blanket implicit which would convert any scala.Double to any AnyRef.
You may wish to use a type ascription: `x: java.lang.Double`.
                       RowFactory.create(mcid, probability(0))
```

Any suggestions to fix this or another approach?

Comment: I ended up just using a udf. This was much easier than what I wrote above.